# Oversee and monitor several scrum projects

Tags: scrum, agile, team-management, project-management-style, measurement

I have to oversight several different scrum project. Which measurements for the health of a project do you regularly look at?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Scrum of Scrums:**

[How to make Scrum of Scrums meetings more productive?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6230/how-to-make-scrum-of-scrums-meetings-more-productive)

**Agile EVM:**

I would also highly recommend to use Agile EVM if you have a budget too.
Theory: http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=61
Practices: http://tempo.io/products/tempo-folio/

**Scaled Agile:**

http://www.scaledagileframework.com/

Comment: Just skimmed Agile EVM. There are some good concepts, but I'm seeing many very dangerous concepts. Do NOT tie actual cost to story points. This is a very very very very BAD idea. God help you if this sort of metric bastardization ever makes it into a contract.

Comment: Agile project's is mostly got time material contracts behind.
But i know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Scrum is all about adding business value and evolving an efficient delivery approach, so these are the things I would measure:

- Stakeholder satisfaction
- Product Owner satisfaction
- Progress against the organisations agile goals (e.g. reducing time-to-market)
- Effectiveness of the Scrum team's retrospectives and adaptions

Comment: To tag on to Barnaby's point here, a couple of other important things to notice:

* Is each team's velocity trending upward? While there can be some fluctuation, generally velocity should increase.
* How are the team's defect rates? If they seem high, the team may be committing too much to each sprint and rushing through it.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you view the above bullet points being connected to adding business value?

Comment: I trust my Product Owner and stakeholders to know what added business value is. If they are satisfied, then chances are it is being added.